# Failed in upload firmware to esp32

Tags: electrical-engineering, circuits, embedded-systems, electronics, microelectronics

I'm having an issue when uploading code to my ESP32. Previously, I had configured the partition scheme to 'minimal,' and I was able to upload code without any problems. However, after I fixed my laptop and reinstalled the Arduino IDE, I reinstalled all libraries. Since then, I have been unable to upload code to my ESP32, even though the compilation process encounters no issues
In a more accurate description, the code uploading process proceeds normally, but the executed code doesn't run as expected. I suspect this issue may be related to the flash memory setup. Does anyone have a deep understanding of the issue I'm facing.
[image: Here is my configuration esp32]

Comment: this would go better in the electronics se

Comment: how can anyone have any understanding of your problem, when we only know that `code doesn't run as expected` and we have no idea what the code is, what it actually does, and what you expect it to do

Comment: I suggest uploading a small blinky or hello world type program to confirm the downloading of the code is working correctly.